# Rails: Designing relations between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

My application needs to implement a functionality for performing competitions of photographers. Process looks like this: Administrator creates a competition, then user can apply a request for participating. Admin can approve request or it can deny it. Admin does it by creating a response with response status field assigned to ACCEPTED (0) or BANNED (100).

```
class Competition
end

class User
end

class CompetitionRequest
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to: competition
end

class CompetitionResponse
 ACCEPTED = 0
 BANNED = 100
 belongs_to :competition_request

end

class Photo
   belongs_to :competition

end
```

But later i need to figure out how to filter banned photos from showing them to users and jury.
And Photo has no direct connection to CompetitionResponse. Photo and CompetitionResponse have relations to Competition but i can not figure out how to make filtration possible. I tried doing it via plain sql (find_by_sql) inside Photo model (it returns records only if appropriate request was approved) but it does not seems to be a good design, because i reference value defined in CompetitionResponse class in Photo model.

Later i changed design and make a before_save filter inside CompetitionResponse model, it checks if status == BANNED and if true, marks all the photos posted to competition by user (who's request was banned) as banned (i added a status field to Photo model).
But now i feel it looks not good. CompetitionRequest model takes too much responsibility.

What is the best way to design it ? May be there must some kind of Observer or something like this or another design pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

First step I would take is assign each Photo to the user it "belongs_to". This will allow you to, at any time, check whether the "owning" user was indeed accepted or banned for the competition that photo refers to...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should have a many-to-many relation between Competition and User. When the admin accepts a user into the competition, you associate the records. This keeps things simple in your data model and also allows for cases where Users get into a Competition without requesting it (perhaps as part of a tournament?).

Also consider getting rid of CompetitionResponse - it seems like this should just be an attribute of CompetitionRequest, as there would only be one response to a request, right?